# Which way is efficient for storing in hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

Assume `my_hash = {:name => "bob", :age => 21}`. I can assign values to the hash in three ways:

Way 1

```
my_hash[:name] = "bob"
my_hash[:age]  =  21
```

Way 2

```
my_hash.store(:name,"bob")
my_hash.store(:age,21)
```

Way 3

```
my_hash = {:name => "bob", :age => 21}
```

Please help me understand value assignment in terms of OS memory. Why are there three ways to assign values to keys, and which way is efficient?

Comment: Last one (way 3) isn't an assignment, it is a creation.

Comment: As way 3 is creation, ignoring that, way 2 is better than way 1. Try benchmarking

Comment: @RAJ : Thanku so much!

Comment: Not doing anything to `my_hash` is the fastest.

Comment: "Way 3" should probably be `my_hash.merge!({:name => "bob", :age => 21})` or maybe `my_hash.replace(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Incase of memory i believe all takes equal memory. I benchmarked each step and these are the results. As you can see speed for each case is just marginally different, not enough difference to choose one over the other.

So you just use the code that you feel natural when writing your code.

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.760000   0.030000   0.790000 (  0.808573) my_hash[:t] = 1
   0.810000   0.030000   0.840000 (  0.842075) my_hash.store(:t, 1)
   0.750000   0.020000   0.770000 (  0.789766) my_hash = {:t => 1}
```

benchmarking script.

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    1000000.times do
      my_hash = {}
      my_hash[:t] = 1
      my_hash[:b] = 2
    end
  end
  x.report do
    1000000.times do
      my_hash = {}
      my_hash.store(:t, 1)
      my_hash.store(:b, 2)
    end
  end
  x.report do
    1000000.times do
      my_hash = {:t => 1, :t => 2}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer benchmark-ips for this sort of thing, because it works out how many times the test should be performed and it also gives you some error margins. For this

```
Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('[]') do |n|
    n.times do
      t  = {}
      t[:x] = 1
    end
  end

  x.report('store') do |n|
    n.times do
      t  = {}
      t.store(:x, 1)
    end
  end
end
```

produces

```
[]         2.082M (±14.6%) i/s -     10.276M
store      1.978M (±13.9%) i/s -      9.790M
```

i.e. the difference is well within the margin of error, This isn't surprising because if you look at the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L3970) then you can see that `[]=` and `store` are actually exactly the same method.